# Python: What modules do I need to include in the directory of my program to run Selenium with Unittest?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, browser, webdriver

I am trying to run the following code using the Pycharm IDE:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("selenium")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I get the following error when I do:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/BigRed/PycharmProjects/python 3/source.py", line 8, in setUp
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Firefox'
```

In the directory of the source file, I also have the selenium folder, which contains the webdriver files, as well as `exceptions.py` and `selenium.py`. Is there something I am missing? Or is the problem something different altogether?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Will you please check `webdriver.py` has `class Firefox` or not?

Comment: It doesn't, no. That's why I'm wondering what other files I need.
I hope someone with experience with selenium can point me in the right direction, as I am new to it

Comment: Source code has file `selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py` in git. Check url https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py

Comment: My webdriver.py is identical to that one

Comment: Then it must work :(. Please check `sys.path` has that directory or not.

Comment: `import sys; print sys.path`                                                  before `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem and i did like this

```
1) open terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
2) check $ python --version
3) now install firefox using pip or sudo apt-get
```

or

```
1) open terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
2) check $ python --version                  (2.7.5....) and 
3) In pycharm go to project interpreter and select the same python version as project interpreter.
```

4) Now run it will work.